# How to allow docker containers to communicate outside network in user-defined networking?

Tags: docker

I can successfully place containers in a docker user-defined network, but if I log into them with

```
docker exec -it 2d6 /bin/sh
```

I can't ping out of that container to machine on the wider network.

What I'm trying to do is run a system where one port of one container only on the user-defined network can be reached from the outside, but containers on the inside can establish connections with the outside.

I created the network with:

```
docker network create --driver bridge isolated_nw
```

Comment: It's a little bit confusing what your asking here.  If you create a user-defined network it's for isolation from other docker networks, but in both cases you don't prevent outbound connections.  So a ping will indeed work as expected.  Also no ports are exposed as default from any running containers, you use the `expose` or `port` for this.

Answer (score 0):

Problem seems to be pings are blocked, but `wget` works fine on my test site (`www.bbc.co.uk`).